# Receiving segmentation fault when trying to read from file in dev c++ mingw 4.8.1

Tags: c++, dev-c++, mingw32

I'm trying to read characters from file but i receive a segmentation fault when i have variables declared outside main. If i delete them and try to read from file, everything works smooth.
I am using dev c++ 5.7.1 with mingw 4.8.1 the portable version.

I've isolated the problem to just having a few variables declared and the file reading code. This piece of code comes from a bigger app that i am trying to develop(i am learning game development on my own).

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <fstream>    
bool running = true;  
bool musicPlaying = true;  
bool read = false;  
int levelNumber;  
int barWidth = 40;  
int barHeight = 10;  
float timeElapsed;  

int main(int argc, char** argv) {    
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open("test.txt");
    std::cout<<file.is_open()<<std::endl;
    char c;
    while(!file.eof()){  
        file.get(c);  
        std::cout<<c;  
    }  
    return 0;  
}
```

I get the output: 1, the file is open. But no character is read from file.
[Debug information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfulx.jpg)

Why is this happening?

Comment: I suggest updating the compiler. GCC 4.8.1 is very old. Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons

Comment: As a new user here, start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your issue, please extract and provide a [mcve] as part of your question. Unused globals should have been stripped unless relevant. Further, don't post pictures if you can use text instead. Also, that `while (!eof){...}` doesn't work, just do a little research on it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. \`while (!stream.eof())\`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: Your code is running well with my compiler. Try to comment out ```bool read = false; ```. it may conflict with read function.

Comment: Perhaps `while (file.get(c)) std::cout << c;`?

Comment: @SoheilArmin that would lead to a compiler "redefinition" error. And GCC 4.7.1 and up don't throw this error anymore.

Comment: @SoheilArmin you were right! The read boolean did conflict with the read function. Commenting it or changing the name to read2 solves the problem. Also, i updated the compiler to 8.2.0(this was the most up to date portable version i could find) and the problem persisted. There seems to be no problem in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your answer to my comment, declaring `bool read` overrides `read` function which is used by the `fread`.
Either rename it or move it to another namespace or class.

None of my compilers could reproduce the same issue. And it's very strange behavior because at least the declaration of *'read'* should be the same as the original one for a proper override. Maybe your *stdlib* is calling read in a different way.